# Session variables being lost before session expires

Tags: asp.net

After a user logs in, I set a Session variable to to store their ID.  This ID is used to load things like their user name. The name will show correctly at first, showing that the Session variable was used.  However if I refresh the page after just a few minutes, the user name is blank, suggesting the Session variable is now gone.

I've read that the default Session timeout is 20 minutes.  I confirmed this in my hosting provider's Asp.net settings.  But the variable is lost well before 20 minutes.

I also read that I should have a Global.asax file with the below code:

```
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
Session.Timeout = 20;
}
```

I did that, but I'm still losing the variable after a few minutes.  I then read that I should place the below code in my web.config:

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="120" />
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

So I did that, but then it produced an error saying: "Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS."

I'm not sure what else to try.  The website I'm creating is in a sub-directory on my domain, the web.config and global.asax files I edited are in that sub-directory, so I wouldn't think there's a conflict elsewhere right?

Answer (score 0):

Your subdirectory is not marked as an application in IIS. This could be part of the problem as you haven't created the application properly. Since it's not marked as an application, certain features of your web.config are illegal since they can only be placed into the root directory of an application.

Other factors though can be the application pool has recycled for some reason. Sometimes due to errors, but also do to other events such as running out of database connections in the connection pool as well as the most famous which is simply storing too many items in session that causes the app pool to run out of memory and recycle.

Since your application is in a subdirectory, it is actually part of another application. In this case anything going on with the main application could be interfering or abandoning the session. The root web.config could have very different session state settings which could make the behavior very different.

Start by setting the sub-directory as an application in IIS and see how it then behaves. After that, if the problem persists start to look for other issues such as memory leaks. You don't want to keep the session extended for too long either. If a user stops doing anything for more than 20 or 30 minutes, chances are they aren't coming back anytime soon. Since session eats memory, having shorter times helps the performance of the application. If you need longer duration storage, it's generally better for performance as well as the application's stability to use a store made for longer term data such as a database.

Comment: Thank you Mark, I'll try that.  Since I'm new to .Net, I didn't think I had to set the sub-directory as an application in IIS since it's a web forms web site and not an application.  I'll give this a shot

Comment: An application in IIS is more like a zone of operation or a self-contained entity. That means anything within it works within it's own memory space. You'll have to be careful because any application will generally inherit the properties of the root application as a default, but you can over-ride them within your own application scope.

Comment: That's great to know, thank you!  This may sound like a stupid question, but I'm very new to .net development.  The website I've been assigned to work on is using Windows hosting, with a php site at the root.  They have an asp.net site in a sub directory now, and have asked me to create this additional .net site in another sub-directory.  Is the php site at the root going to cause a conflict? I don't know why they set it up like this.  I'm going to follow your instructions to set this directory as an application, but figured I'd ask this in case it could cause another issue

Comment: It shouldn't. The PHP site will be running in it's own application space and also runs through it's own processing pipeline. You can actually co-exist ASP.Net and PHP within the same application pool, but it's good if you can keep them separate as it's easier on memory usage.

Comment: Thank you again Mark.  I made the changes suggested and I'm still getting the same problem.  From doing some more reading, could it be because this website is being hosted on a shared hosting platform? So subsequent requests could be routed elsewhere and not maintain the session? If so I guess I should look into alternatives to the regular session variables